# preg_replace - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

having a bit of trouble with replacing things that are NOT 0-9A-Za-z[:space] because I cannot find a NOT metachar for preg_replace. Does anytone know if one exists and if not what is the best way to strip anything that is NOT alpha numeric or a space?

Comment: Please accept an answer that you feel has helped you the most. You should do this because it provides valuable feedback to the answerers. You can do this by clicking the check mark next to the answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negated character classes:

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/
```

You could also use the `\w` escape sequence, which is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (note the underscore). So your regex would look like

```
/[^\w ]/
```

#### Reference:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: @Alex: You should also accept one of the answers given you; that is how Stack Overflow works. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

More useful:

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/
```